# load file and write in xml or html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I am curious if this is possible:

on the website:

1. using jquery to get value from a html tag and store the value as a variable
2. using ajax to call a file (xml, html or txt) on servside or external site for a php file
3. define the current value in the xml html or txt file
4. and add this value to the current value. = new value
5. store this new value in the xml html or txt (saving the file on server...)

Q1. Is this achievable?

Q2. If so, what file is best used/supported? (php would be my very last alternative option) I prefer xml and html...

Q3. step 1 to 4 i can get to work - but step 5 i have totally no experience in. Anyone can guide me the right direction for writing those documents?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write the file directly in the server using javascript.

What you can do, for example, is send the updated data to a page in the server (sending a request to a PHP page, or a MVC endpoint, or whatever server-side technology you want to use) and then have the server code update the file using that data.

You can do this with AJAX (eg. using jQuery with [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) if you want it to happen in the background, or with a normal request (which will reload the page or take the user elsewhere depending on the server code).